# How to divide two numbers in swift using two variables?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know what is the problem here. When I divide (in return statement), it gives me "Invalid character in source file".

I tried give some space between 'sum' and 'numbers', but nothing works for me.

```
func sumOf(numbers:Int...)->(Int) {
    var sum=0
    for numbers in numbers {
        sum+=numbers
        //
    }
    //println("\(numbers)")
    return sum/numbers

}
```

Comment: the divide operator is `/`

Comment: ya i tried '/' also  it gives me 'could not find an overload for / that accepts the supplied argument'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Division operator is `/`, not `\`.
2. `sum\numbers` - um, what? Did you mean `sum / numbers.count` ?

Answer (score 4):

> `return sum\numbers`

I think you probably meant to use the slash (`/`) character instead of a backslash.

Also, I'm surprised you got past this:

> `for numbers in numbers {`

Seems like you should use a different name for the iterator variable than you used for the parameter, like this:

```
for n in numbers {
```

Comment: return sum\numbers also give me error "invalid character in source file"

Comment: @guru Yes, of course it does... I'm quoting your code there to point to the problem. I explained what's wrong with it below. You should use `sum/numbers` rather than `sum\numbers`.

Comment: There's no reason that the compiler should give you an error about using the same name for the loop variable, it just means that whatever you're iterating over will be shadowed for the duration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "/" to divide, not "\".

So,

```
return sum/numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the "for" statement, "numbers" is an array.  You can't divide an Int by an array type (unless you overload the / operator, maybe to produce an array result?).  Perhaps you want to use the array count instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since numbers is a List you can't divide by it. You should use `numbers.count`. Also you had an error in your `for`-loop, you should add `number` and not `number_s_`

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum / numbers.count
}
```